# PHP MySQL Assign foreign keys duplicated in DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, alter-table, querying

I have the following code:

```
$fkQuery = "SELECT TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_NAME, KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.COLUMN_NAME, KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS RIGHT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ON INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_NAME = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.CONSTRAINT_NAME WHERE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.CONSTRAINT_NAME <> 'PRIMARY' AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_SCHEMA = '".$dbName."';"; 

$fkQueryResult = $newLink->query($fkQuery); 

$a = 0;

while($fkey = $fkQueryResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $testF[] = $fkey; 
    $assocF = $testF[$a]; 

    $newTableName = $assocF['TABLE_NAME']; 
    $newColumnName = $assocF['COLUMN_NAME']; 
    $newRefTableName = $assocF['REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME']; 
    $newRefColumnName = $assocF['REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME']; 

    $addFkToTable = "ALTER TABLE " . $newDbName . "." . $newTableName . " ADD FOREIGN KEY (" . $newColumnName . ") REFERENCES " . $dbName . "." . $newRefTableName . "(" . $newRefColumnName . ");";

    echo $addFkToTable . "\n"; 

    $newLink->query($addFkToTable); 

    $a++; 
}
```

This will select all of the foreign key references from the old table in the old database so that they can be relayed into the new database table. This is working, except it is doubling each foreign key relationship. So, for example, I have TableA(columnA) that references TableB(columnB). When I run the fkQuery against the database, it will return that the fk exists, but will list it twice. Any suggestions as to how to remedy that?

Comment: What about dumping SQL and manually change it? Should this be some migration tool?

Comment: PHP and MySQL were required uses

Comment: I checked your query, it works. I don't understand `it will return that the fk exists, but will list it twice`. The result of your query is fine? You have problems with the `ALTER` statements?

Comment: So I have this:
TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | REF_TBL_NAME | REF_COL_NAME -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Customer        | salesRepNumber | Employee            | EmployeeNumber
Customer        | salesRepNumber | Employee            | EmployeeNumber

Comment: That didn't come out formatted right. The table will list each value twice, as if each foreign key relationship had been created twice in the same table.

Comment: I suspect you are its with the strange thing you are doing with your indexing and what not via `$a`. I suspect things are getting out of sync somehow. Is there a specific reason you are doing this?

Comment: Just to index through the array at that spot in the encompassing array

Comment: @Skyfactor_interns Id try using `$testF[$a] = $fkey` so that the indexes are explicit if you want to do this. Though if this were my code i would pull the data for the `ALTER` directly from `$fkey` and then if it succeeded push it into `$testF[]`. This way the specific index doesnt matter.

Comment: That didn't fix the issue. I have discovered that I am referencing the new tables in the new database (one set of foreign keys) and the old tables are being referenced by the new tables (which explains why the relationships are showing up twice). So the foreign keys are referencing the old database tables and the new database tables.

Comment: It should only reference the new tables.

Comment: I have also tried changing $dbName in the $addToFkToTable to $newDbName, and the foreign keys do not get created at all.